# Tag Badges Not Tracking

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, badges

On the main site I have one answer in [beer-styles](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer-styles) which has nine votes, but the [beer-styles](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer-styles) tag does not show up in my **Next Tag Badge** list. In fact, of the nine tags in which I have participated, only two appear to be trackable. Is this a (known) bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be eligible for an associated badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836) - [beer-styles](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer-styles) currently appears on only 46, so no one will be earning badges for it just yet.